# D3 Tooltip on small multiples

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm unable to display tooltips on each circle in a small multiples d3 graph (with d3-tip). I've got the following error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of null".

I think the problem is in the definition of my "tip" variable. I'm not sure which key I should define.

Does anybody have a hint?

Thank you in advance,

Florent

```
<script>

var margin = {top: 8, right: 10, bottom: 2, left: 10},
    width = 635 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 50 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y.%m.%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });



d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  var keys = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.key; })
      .sortValues(function(a,b) { return d3.ascending(a.date, b.date)})
      .entries(data);

  x.domain([
    d3.min(keys, function(key) { return key.values[0].date; }),
    d3.max(keys, function(key) { return key.values[key.values.length - 1].date; })
  ]);

  var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
      .data(keys)
    .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .each(multiple);

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 6)
      .attr("y", height - 6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

});

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>" + d.value + "</strong>"
    // + "\t" 
    // + year.values + "</strong><br/><span style='color:#fff'>" + value.values + " députés élus"
    ;
  })

function multiple(key) {
  var svg = d3.select(this);

  y.domain([0, d3.max(key.values, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area(key.values));

  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line(key.values));


 svg.selectAll(".circle")
     .data(key.values)
     .enter()
     .append("svg:circle")
     .attr("class", "circle")
     .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
     return x(d.date);
 })
     .attr("cy", function (d, i) {
     return y(d.value);
 })
     .attr("r", 5)
     .on('mouseover', tip.show)
     .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
     console.log(key.values)

}
```

Comment: Where is the error message coming from?

Comment: In the console, when my mouse is on the circle (which should display the tooltip).

Comment: And what line of code is causing it?

Comment: It's not clear:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of null
p @ d3.tip.min.js:1
o @ d3.tip.min.js:1
t.show @ d3.tip.min.js:1
(anonymous function) @ d3.min.js:1

Comment: Oh you haven't set it up yet, have you? `svg.call(tip)`

Comment: ....Thanks ... (I feel pretty dumb right now) :)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. I thought this may have been a issue with circles not having a 'x' or 'y' value. Turns out I was just missing

```
svg.call(tip);
```

Comment: Indeed. Now, I never forget ;)